# In "The Dark Knight," how old was Rachel Dawes?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

She appears to be a childhood friend of Bruce and Harvey.

Comment: *Rachel is Bruce Wayne's closest childhood friend. Rachel's mother worked as a domestic servant at Wayne Manor, and the two would often play together on the grounds* - So, approximately the same age as Bruce, give or take.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the screenplay for *Batman Begins*, Rachel was 10 years old when Bruce was 8.

> BLACK. A low KEENING which becomes SCREECHING that BUILDS and BUILDS until- RED flickers through black as the screen BURSTS into life: Clouds of REELING BATS silhouetted against a blood red sky, bolting away from camera, MASSING in the
> sky... FORMING a density the shape of an enormous BAT-LIKE SYMBOL. More BATS mass, swamping the symbol, DARKENING the screen to- BLACK. Distant children’s LAUGHTER which comes closer as- SUNLIGHT flickers through black. Sunlight through
> trees running through a SUMMER GARDEN. A BOY. Chasing a GIRL. The Boy reaches a Victorian GREENHOUSE. Stands in the doorway catching his breath. **This is Bruce Wayne, aged 8,** and we are-
>
> 1 EXT. GARDENS, WAYNE MANOR -- DAY 1
>
> YOUNG BRUCE peers down rows of plants on long trestle tables.
>
> YOUNG BRUCE: Rachel?
>
> No response. Sunlight streams through wrought iron and glass. Young Bruce advances, cautious. He is GRABBED from behind and pulled under a table by **a young girl, aged 10. This is RACHEL.**
>
> <sub>[*Batman Begins* (2005) - screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/scripts/batman-begins-2005.pdf)</sub>

The screenplay also notes that she was 23 years old when he was 20.

> Amongst them, Bruce, AGED 20, holding a bag. He sees Alfred,
> now 62, craning his neck, SEARCHING. He waves.
>
> [...]
>
> Rachel, now 23, stands by her car looking up at the house.
> She can see Bruce in the window. She gives a small wave.
>
> <sub>*Batman Begins* (2005) - screenplay</sub>

So that'd presumably make her *two-point-something* years older than Bruce.

The screenplay indicates that Bruce returned to Gotham from Bhutan three months prior to his thirtieth birthday.

> BOARD MEMBER: Is he taking over?
>
> EARLE: Not yet. I checked the trust, and **Bruce can’t assume control until his thirtieth birthday.**
>
> (presses intercom)
>
> EARLE: Jessica, where’s that coffee?
>
> BOARD MEMBER: **But that’s in three months.**
>
> <sub>*Batman Begins* (2005) - screenplay</sub>

He subsequently becomes Batman *before* his thirtieth birthday party (which is shown in the film), and has his final confrontation with Ra's al Ghul *after* said birthday.

The following dialogue from *The Dark Knight* suggests that film takes place no more than a year or so after Batman first appeared in Gotham.

> JOKER: **Let's wind the clocks back a year. These cops and lawyers wouldn't dare cross any of you. I mean, what happened? Did your balls drop off?** Hm? You see, a guy like me...
>
> GAMBOL: A freak.
>
> MOBSTER 1: Damn right.
>
> JOKER: A guy like me... Look, listen. **I know why you choose to have your little, ahem... group-therapy sessions in broad daylight. I know why you're afraid to go out at night. The Batman. See, Batman has shown Gotham your true colors, unfortunately.** Dent, he's just the beginning.
>
> <sub>[*The Dark Knight* (2008) - transcript](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=953&t=36764)</sub>

So that'd make Bruce either 30 or 31 in *The Dark Knight*. And with Rachel being two-point-something years older, she could be as young as 32 or as old as 34.